# Showoff Gallery doesn't work - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I don't know if any of you guys can help me out, but I've just purchased this plugin called Showoff and it doesn't work properly on my site - When clicking on the images, the description box doesn’t show up, but I can see the description text behind the other images. (There’s only description on the second image “Zink Design” in the gallery right now) The link to my site is http://live-it.dk/portfolio/

I have tried to get in touch with their own support, but the only answer they gave me was this:
"Make sure you have only one jquery loaded at all times and is loaded before every other js script that depend on jquery."

I think that I only have one jquery, but I'm fairly new with both html, css and javascript and so on, so I can't really get any further with this. 
The gallery should look like this: http://codecanyon.net/item/showoff/full_screen_preview/6585732

Really hope you can help me, I am going to apply for internship this week, so I would really appreciate your help, so my site can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page is including a *lot* of things, so this may not be the only problem.  But you're doing *exactly* what their support said not to do, including two separate versions of jQuery:

```
<script src="http://live-it.dk/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0" type="text/javascript">
...
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: Well, can I just delete one of them or? I really don't know anything about jquery, that's why I am asking in here :/

Comment: @CarinaMurielConradsen: Probably?  I can't say for certain, you may be using something that has a tight coupling to a specific version of jQuery.  I would recommend loading only the more recent version (1.11.0 in this case) and making sure to load it before anything which depends on it.  Then test the functionality again and make sure things are still working.